# Ejabber XMMP Services for iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, ejabberd, mobile-application, xmppframework

I'm developing a chat app using Ejabber XMPP for ios. I'm able to connect and Authenticate to the server. i'm able to see online and offline users also. but i have an issue with the below i search alot but not found solutions for that can someone help me on this things asked below:

1. How to upload logged-in user avatar as a display pic.
2. How to a person i'm using below method but it is not adding, i'm using simulator to add the user. if i add in android app it is displaying in my simulator.

   -(void)addUser:(XMPPJID *)jid withNickname:(NSString *)optionalName;

but how to call the above method

3. How to disable account temporarily
4. How to delete account
5. How to share audio/video/photo files in chat
6. How to create a group

Comment: use XMPPIncomingFileTranfer and XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer files in your project to share Video, Aduio, Photo, PDF, DOC file.

Comment: @AshokLondhe thank you, do u have any sample how to call the methods in it

Comment: actually i have done that separately.. i have done integrated. you can first download that files and create sample project and check it. and then integrate it.

Comment: @AshokLondhe can you please share the code...

Comment: Currently i don't have code. you can download these files and add it into you project and if you requires any help i will help you.

Comment: @AshokLondhe do you know how to get group list using XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject or the other way